# How to use dictionary comprehension to combine two lists into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to combine the following lists into a nested dictionary using list comprehension.

```
dates = ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-07', '2023-04-17', '2023-04-19', '2023-04-25']
events_name = [
    'PyTexas', 'PyCamp Spain', 'PyData Berlin', 'PyCon US', 'PyLadies Amsterdam']
```

The dictionary should look like this:

```
python_events = {
    0: {'time': '2023-04-01', 'name': 'PyTexas'}, 
    1: {'time': '2023-04-07', 'name': 'PyCamp Spain'},
    2: {'time': '2023-04-17', 'name': 'PyData Berlin'},
    3: {'time': '2023-04-19', 'name': 'PyCon US'},
    4: {'time': '2023-04-25', 'name': 'PyLadies Amsterdam'}}
```

I am trying to use dictonary comprehension mostly for learning and practice. It seems like a bad use case for comprehension since it most likely will not be readable at all, or at least doesn't seem like it to me

My original way of creating the dict was looping through a range:

```
for i in range(0, len(dates)):
    python_events[i] = {"time": dates[i], "name": events_name[i]}
```

Even after some research, and using comprehension for non nested dicts, I never managed to get valid code for my comprehension. I tried multiple variants of this:

```
python_events = {
    i: {"time": date, "name": name for date, name in dict(foo).items()}
    for i, date, name in range(0, len(events))}
```

I'm clearly missing some fundamental knowledge here, so any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `dict` comprehension to make `python_events` like this:

```py
dates = ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-07', '2023-04-17', '2023-04-19', '2023-04-25']
events_name = ['PyTexas', 'PyCamp Spain', 'PyData Berlin', 'PyCon US', 'PyLadies Amsterdam']


python_events = {i:{"time": date,"name": name } for i, (date, name) in enumerate(zip(dates,events_name))}
print(python_events)
```

Output as requested.

This code uses `zip` to iterate through your two lists at the same time and also `enumerate` to generate the index `i`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, I was also heading towards the zip method but I couldnt get the correct iterrable placement, thought they had to be in the actual nested dictionary. Great help, and it doesn't look as bad as I originally thought it would :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate indices, and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine two lists pair-wise:

```
from pprint import pprint

dates = ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-07', '2023-04-17', '2023-04-19', '2023-04-25']
events_name = ['PyTexas', 'PyCamp Spain', 'PyData Berlin', 'PyCon US', 'PyLadies Amsterdam']

python_events = {i: {'time': date, 'name': event}
                 for i, (date, event) in enumerate(zip(dates, events_name))}

pprint(python_events)
```

Output:

```
{0: {'name': 'PyTexas', 'time': '2023-04-01'},
 1: {'name': 'PyCamp Spain', 'time': '2023-04-07'},
 2: {'name': 'PyData Berlin', 'time': '2023-04-17'},
 3: {'name': 'PyCon US', 'time': '2023-04-19'},
 4: {'name': 'PyLadies Amsterdam', 'time': '2023-04-25'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to converting a for-loop to a comprehension is knowing the pattern. Here's some pseudocode:

```
d = {}
for x in iterable:
    d[key_expression] = value_expression
```

That rearranges into a comprehension like this:

```
d = {key_expression: value_expression for x in iterable}
```

Note that `for x in iterable` is exactly the same, just at the end, and the two expressions don't need to change at all.

So, for your code:

```
python_events = {
    i: {"time": dates[i], "name": events_name[i]} for i in range(0, len(dates))}
```

That said, you can use `zip` and `enumerate` to do this more cleanly, as others have answered.